# How to run test in IntelliJ IDEA project from InteliJ plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I'm creating plugin for IntelliJ in JAVA I need to find a way how to run tests of opened project in idea trough IntelliJ Plugin. Is there any possible way to do that ?

Comment: you need to donwload https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community and look how they do it

Comment: Do you want to test your plug-in or do you want to execute run/debug configurations as a part of your plug-in functionality?